# What is the best practice for saving iPhone video & pictures?

Tags: backup, iphone, icloud

I have an iPhone 4S and have it backed up via iCloud, Photostream turned on, and iTunes sync over WiFi enabled. Unfortunately, my daughter (2 yrs) got a hold of the iPhone and started deleting photos, which then deleted them from pretty much every place those pics/videos were. By the time I realized the data was delete, the phone was synced and there was no way to restore the data that I know of (suggestions here would be helpful as well!).

What's the proper/suggested way to "dump" the photos and videos from the iPhone to a more permanent store, such as on my MacMini's local drive?

Comment: Is copying them from the `Image Capture` app not enough?

Comment: Not sure. I'll check that out.

Comment: I've reopened that question. Smartphones interfacing with a computer are not off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My recommendation** for backing up your iPhone pictures and/or videos is to:

1. Connect your iPhone to your MacMini
2. Open iPhoto
3. Click on your iPhone device ( left column ) and choose to import any or all media taken from your camera roll.

Note: You will have the option here to delete photos imported from your camera roll if desired.  This is my current method of backing up /importing all of my media taken from my camera roll on my 4S.  iPhoto also has a nice method of creating albums as well.

**Photo recovery suggestion:**   If you performed a data backup of your phone with the photos on it, you can try to restore that backup to obtain those pictures back.  ( **NOTE** this will remove any changes to your contacts, media, etc that you have made since your last backup ! )

It seems if your iPhone has already been synced with iCloud, [you cannot recover those pictures from iCloud](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4393047?start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 0):

I know that if you plug the phone into a Windows machine, it will be recognized as a removable device. From there you can browse to it's DCIM folder and simply copy everything out.

I'm sure something similar is available on a Mac, but, not owning one, I don't know the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore the deleted photos/videos from iTunes backup. Just connect your iPhone to your computer through iTunes. If you backed your iPhone on iTunes, you will have a choice "Restore  backup". Click it.
[image]